# HTML link of image doesn' work

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="~/Content/Img/tr.png" alt="Türkçe" />
    </a>
    <a href="index_en.html">
        <img src="~/Content/Img/eng.png" alt="English" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I have this block of html in my home page. Images show but link does not work. In fact if I remove the style it starts to work. I am very confused.

Comment: Could we have a link to your website, please? It's hard to tell what's going on just from that, but my guess is that you need to set a `z-index` value.

Comment: http://www.partymag.org

Comment: Have you tried my answer?  I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `on-top` to the images and use the below CSS.

HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img class="on-top" src="~/Content/Img/tr.png" alt="Türkçe" />
    </a>
    <a href="index_en.html">
        <img class="on-top" src="~/Content/Img/eng.png" alt="English" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.on-top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I have been struggling with this. It is unfortunate that I cannot upvote. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Some element was overlapping your links, just add `z-index: 1;` in your `<div>` style, **jaunt** got the answer!

```
<div style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; top:0; right:0">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/tr.png" alt="Türkçe">
    </a>
    <a href="index_en.html">
        <img src="images/eng.png" alt="English">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a z-index to the `div` that surrounds your links.

Right now `<div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:776px;">`is sitting on top of the `div` you're having issues with.

Add this to the div that you are having issues with:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:999;">
```

Comment: true, I was adding 999 based on the design to insure it stays on top

Comment: I did it, but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you have another DIV that happens to be overlapping this

I would change the first line to something like this and it should work

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index=1000" >
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Send me your code or put it on https://jsfiddle.net/ and I'll try to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you can either set `z-index:1` in the parent `div` or you can apply

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
```

and

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:40px;
```

to the `img` tags inside the `a` tags instead of the parent `div`. I'm sure there are other ways too, but these seems the easiest.